# Does a dev branch should be deleted after every merged and then create?

Tags: git, merge

If there is a branch name `dev`, it is a normal develop branch.

Should I delete it after every merge and then create a new one?

If do not delete, the branch network is(all merge use `--no-ff`):

```
*   0019d6a - (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'dev' second (2 minutes ago)
|\
| * e6dcaf5 - (dev) add b.file (2 minutes ago)
* |   c39915b - Merge branch 'dev' (3 minutes ago)
|\ \
| |/
| * 352afa1 - add a.file (4 minutes ago)
|/
* d06fb93 - init (4 minutes ago)
```

The version `c39915b` is the first merge, and then go on develop, do the second merge.

If I delete and create a new one, it will start from version `c39915b`:

```
*   4a4b8dc - (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'dev' second (7 seconds ago)
|\
| * afd5dfe - (dev) add b.file (16 seconds ago)
|/
*   c39915b - Merge branch 'dev' (3 minutes ago)
|\
| * 352afa1 - add a.file (4 minutes ago)
|/
* d06fb93 - init (4 minutes ago)
```

In the second situation, the branch network in clear than the first one.

I don't know which one is better?

---

Append:

I read [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and find this picture:

[image: git-flow]

It use the first one and keep the dev branch as a long-term branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the second method is just a lot more work over time with absolutely no benefit.

Stick with the branch and keep merging it. Moreover, you can get the second type history even if you stick with branch all the way. Whenever you make a change directly to master, merge it in dev (not dev in master, the other way round) to bring the dev branch up to date.

Comment: Yes, I think so. `dev` branch as a long-term branch, no need to delete. The second is fit for such as `feature` or `fixbug` branch and merge to dev.

Comment: True. If you are going to need the branch, no need deleting it. On the other hand, bug fixes are generally short lived branches and are created and deleted as seen fit.